# c# wpf full stop on wrong side

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application with a form that contains the following XAML:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!-- reverse order, because of flow direction-->
    <Button Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="101"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" IsDefault="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="100"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Warning}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red" />
</StackPanel>
```

It is for a form to save or discard changes. The form is connected to a view model containing two commands (`SaveCommand`,`CancelCommand`) and a property `Warning`.

I have the following problem with this: When the property `Warning` of the view model returns the `string` "This is a important warning." the dot at the end is appearing in the left side. When running the application, the text on the form looks like this: ".This is a important warning".

Can anybody please help me.

Comment: 1. Check the return value of Warning property. 2. Give some code of view model

Comment: I have already checked the return value of the Warning property. It's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FlowDirection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.flowdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) property is inherited by child elements:

> Because of property value inheritance, setting FlowDirection on an element can potentially set FlowDirection on all child elements that did not set FlowDirection locally or though other means such as styles.

You should set the `FlowDirection` of the `TextBlock` back to "LeftToRight".

Comment: LeftToRight - > This is a important warning. RightToLeft  -.gninraw tnatropmi a si sihT.....??

Comment: @goodeinstein - apparently not :) I suspect that as it's still English the words come out in the right order.

Comment: I don't know why the text is not reversed but just the dot. But this answer solved my problem. Thanx